# Ngram filter works differently than I thought

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index with the following mapping,

```
curl -XPUT http://ubuntu:9200/ngram-test -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "mynGram": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "domain_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "mynGram"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "assets": {
            "properties": {
                "domain": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
                },
                "tag": {
                    "include_in_parent": true,
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'; echo
```

Then I added some documents,

```
curl http://ubuntu:9200/ngram-test/assets/ -d '{
  "domain": "www.example.com",
  "tag": [
    {
      "name": "IIS"
    },
    {
      "name": "Microsoft ASP.NET"
    }
  ]
}'; echo
```

But from the query validate,

```
http://ubuntu:9200/ngram-test/_validate/query?q=tag.name:asp.net&explain
```

The query has become this,

```
filtered(tag.name:a tag.name:as tag.name:asp tag.name:asp. tag.name:asp.n tag.name:asp.ne tag.name:asp.net tag.name:s tag.name:sp tag.name:sp. tag.name:sp.n tag.name:sp.ne tag.name:sp.net tag.name:p tag.name:p. tag.name:p.n tag.name:p.ne tag.name:p.net tag.name:. tag.name:.n tag.name:.ne tag.name:.net tag.name:n tag.name:ne tag.name:net tag.name:e tag.name:et tag.name:t)->cache(org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter@ad04e78f)
```

Totally unexpected. I was expecting `asp.net*` or `*asp.net` or `*asp.net*` like queries, not things like `tag.name:a`,

That means when I query for `asp.net`, things like `alex` will appear in search result as well, that's totally wrong.

Did I miss something?

### EDIT

I increased min_gram to 5, and added search_analyzer

```
        "tag": {
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "domain_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
```

But from validate, it is still unexpected:

```
# http://ubuntu:9200/tag-test/assets/_validate/query?explain&q=tag.name:microso
filtered(tag.name:micro tag.name:micros tag.name:microso tag.name:icros tag.name:icroso tag.name:croso)->cache(_type:assets)
```

Hmm ... it still contains search for `icros icroso croso`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An nGram token filter will split your tokens at the character level. If all you need is to split on words, your whitespace tokenizer already does the job.

Using the [elyzer tool](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer), you get insights into each step of the analysis process. Using your analyzer, it yields this:

```
> elyzer --es localhost:9200 --index ngram --analyzer domain_analyzer --text "Microsoft ASP.NET"

TOKENIZER: whitespace
{1:Microsoft}   {2:ASP.NET} 
TOKEN_FILTER: lowercase
{1:microsoft}   {2:asp.net} 
TOKEN_FILTER: mynGram
{1:m,mi,mic,micr,micro,micros,microso,microsof,microsoft,i,ic,icr,icro,icros,icroso,icrosof,icrosoft,c,cr,cro,cros,croso,crosof,crosoft,r,ro,ros,roso,rosof,rosoft,o,os,oso,osof,osoft,s,so,sof,soft,o,of,oft,f,ft,t}   {2:a,as,asp,asp.,asp.n,asp.ne,asp.net,s,sp,sp.,sp.n,sp.ne,sp.net,p,p.,p.n,p.ne,p.net,.,.n,.ne,.net,n,ne,net,e,et,t}
```

Although what you seem to be willing is more something like this:

```
TOKENIZER: whitespace
{1:Microsoft}   {2:ASP.NET} 
TOKEN_FILTER: lowercase
{1:microsoft}   {2:asp.net}
```

And that can be achieved by removing the `mynGram` token filter from your analyzer.

Comment: Thanks Val, +1 for elyzer tool. I wanted queries for `micro,micros,microso,microsof,microsoft`, not `m,mi,mic,micr,micro,micros,microso,microsof,microsoft` and any other keyword contains `micro` .. Is there anything like that? So far I had to use `*micro*` to accomplish that, which is not recommended

Comment: Oh in that case, you can still use the nGram token filter, but with `min_gram = 5`. Also you probably need to not use the same analyzer at search time, i.e. try to set `"search_analyzer": "standard"` so that your nGram token filter is only used at indexing time.

Comment: You need to use an edge-ngram token filter if you only want the prefixes. After changing that, make sure to reindex your data.